# Unable to get the Backbone View working for a simple example

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am trying to write a simple example using Backbone.js for study. Some how nothing gets printed in the browser. Need a little help here. The code is given below.

**Html:**

```
<div id="container">
    <ul id="person-list">
    </ul>
</div>
```

**Models**

```
var Person = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        id: 0,
        name: ''
    }
});

var PersonStore = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Person,
    url: 'api/person', //currently not using
    initialize: function () {
        console.log("Store initialize");
    }
});
```

**Views**

```
var PersonView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'li',
    initialize: function () {
        _.bindAll(this, "render");
    },
    render: function () {
        $(this.el).append(this.model.name) //model.name shows undefined here
        return this;
    }
});

var PersonListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $('#person-list'),
    tagName:'ul',
    initialize: function () {
        _.bindAll(this, "render");
        this.render();
    },
    render: function () {
        self = this;
        this.collection.each(function (person) { //name property undefined here on person
            var personView = new PersonView({ model: person });
            $(self.el).append(personView.render().el);
        });
    }
});
```

**Sample Run**

```
var persons = new PersonStore([
     new Person({id:1, name: "Person 1"}),
     new Person({ id: 2, name: "Person 2" }),
]);
new PersonListView({ collection: persons });
```

The above setup prints nothing(blank) on screen. I have struggled now for some time and need a little help here as to why the two Person's name does not get displayed in the browser.

Comment: you have to define template for PersonView

Comment: I am not sure I understand you. I have a tagName set to "li" and so in the render, I just append the Person's name (model.name) to that el. I think that is enough for backbone to construct a "li" tag with Person's name. The problem is that the "person" object that I pass to the PersonView has "name" property undefined !

Comment: oh, sorry, missed this - replace  $(this.el).append(this.model.name) with $(this.el).append(this.model.get('name')) - should help

Comment: You got it working. Thanks. Is that the standard way to access the model property values? Also, you may want to post your comment as answer, so that I can mark it as solution.

Comment: You're missing a `var` on `self = this;` and you could `this.collection.each(..., this)` to avoid `self` altogether.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make your code work you have to replace

```
this.$el.append(this.model.name)
```

with

```
this.$el.append(this.model.get('name'))
```

Always use method `.get()` to access model properties.

Also i highly recommend you use templates for rendering views. This approach let you write `.render()` implementation once and will be no need to change it if you need visual changes, you can make in template

Comment: You can replace `$(this.el)` with `this.$el`